# Insert into temp table from SELECT giving strange error

Tags: sql-server

EDIT: I have since been corrected that I need to be doing an update to achieve my intended results. At this point, I'm not able to get the UPDATE statement to do what I want it to, despite my select statement giving me exactly what I want.

```
begin tran
update #cal1
set calendar_key =
(
SELECT 16801 - 1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY CalendarDate
        ) )
FROM #cal1
```

The results from this give me a repeating 16801 in this column as opposed to going down through the numbers as in my select statement. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you insert a value into `calendar_key` only, what value do you expect to find in `Holiday` for the same row?

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear to yoU?

Comment: Apologies, I mistakenly was using INSERT when I should have been using UPDATE.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by putting my SELECT statement results into another temp table along with the date column to act as a unique identifier, then joined this with my original table to get the result set I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error seems rather clear and obvious: since you're **not specifying** the `Holiday` column in your `INSERT` statement (in the list of columns you're inserting into), no value is being inserted into `Holiday` - this is stays `NULL`.

And it appears from the error message that the `Holiday` does **not** allow `NULL` - you need to explicitly provide a value!

```
INSERT INTO #cal1 (calendar_key, Holiday)
    SELECT 
        16801 - 1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY CalendarDate) AS count,
        -some-value-for-holiday-here-
    FROM #cal1
```

Other than explicitly providing a value, you could also:

1. Make the `Holiday` column nullable, so it would be fine with a `NULL`
2. Provide a **default constraint** for `Holiday`, so that if you don't provide a value, the defined default will be used instead

**UPDATE:**

Seeing that you say

*The problem here is that the other values are as they should be. Is there not a way I can add data to just this one column?*

Do you **really** want to `INSERT` a new row?? Or would you much rather want to **UPDATE** an existing row and set just that `calendar_key` column's value?? In that case, you need an `UPDATE` statement - not an `INSERT` ......

Comment: I think I see what you mean. The problem here is that the other values are as they should be. Is there not a way I can add data to just this one column?

Comment: @jw11432: no, you **cannot** insert just a single column - `INSERT` always inserts a **complete row** (with all the columns). But do you really want to **INSERT** a new row?? Or are you really trying to **UPDATE** an existing row (and set just that `calendar_key` column?? Then you need an `UPDATE` statement - not an `INSERT`.......

Comment: You're absolutely right. Update is the correct action here, thank you. Now I'm playing with that trying to get the intended results.